# Is there a hadith on repentance that says "Repentance is sorrow"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, tawba

I remember reading a hadith where our beloved Prophet(peace be upon him) said:

> "Repentance is sorrow"(note that it is the English translation and may not accurately describe the arabic meaning)

But I cannot find this hadith. Can someone confirm if this hadith exists and if it is sahih?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a hadith with very similar wording in Sunan Ibn Majah, the Book of Zuhd, out of which a quote is provided below:

> عَنِ ابْنِ مَعْقِلٍ قَالَ‏:‏ دَخَلْتُ مَعَ أَبِي عَلَى عَبْدِ اللَّهِ فَسَمِعْتُهُ يَقُولُ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ﷺ:‏‏ النَّدَمُ تَوْبَةٌ
>
> It was narrated that Ibn Ma'qil said: I entered with my father upon 'Abdullah, and I heard him say: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Regret is repentance."
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Ibn Majah, Book 37, Hadith 4393](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1343920)</sub>

There are other hadiths that convey the same meaning with different wording, e.g., in [Sunan an-Nasa'i 4068](https://www.sunnah.com/nasai/37/103) (grade: Sahih) and [Sunan Abi Dawud 4273](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/37/34) (grade: Sahih).

As for the specific hadith in Sunan Ibn Majah, it has been documented in multiple books (e.g., Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba Hadith 179, Musnad Ahmad Hadith 4113, Sahih Ibn Hibban Hadith 613, Al-Mustadrak Hadith 7695, among others). The hadith is authentic (grade: Sahih) through multiple narration chains (hence being in Al-Mustadrak), as in Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba ('Abdullah Ibn Mohammad → Waki' Ibn Al-Jarrah → Sufian Ibn Sa'eed → 'Abdul-Karim Ibn Malik → Ziad Ibn Abu Maryam → 'Abdullah Ibn Ma'qil and his father Ma'qil Ibn Muqrin → 'Abdullah ibn Ma'ood) and in Musnad Ahmad (Ahmad Ibn Mohammad → Kathir Ibn Hisham → Furat Ibn Sulaiman → 'Abdul-Karim Ibn Malik → Ziad Ibn Al-Jarrah → 'Abdullah Ibn Ma'qil and his father Ma'qil Ibn Muqrin → 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ood).

The narration specific to the hadith in Sunan Ibn Majah, though, has Hisham Ibn 'Ammar in its chain — who is trustworthy, but in his old age his memory became weak, so this hadith narration chain is graded Hassan.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Prophet said, الندم توبة (regret is repentance).

The source is Ibn Majah (4252).

[(Read here for full hadith and narrators)](https://sunnah.com/urn/1343920).

It is also recorded in the book of Ahmad.

It is said to be authentic. It is included in Sahih Al Jaami.

Answer (score -1):

> “Regret is repentance.”— Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him)
>
> Al-Agharr Al-Muzanee (May Allah be pleased with him) narrated that Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon him) said: “O people ! Repent to Allah and seek for His forgiveness. Verily, I seek repentance from him a hundred times a day.” – [Sahih Muslim]
>
> “Allah holds out His Hand during the night to receive the repentance of the one who has committed wrong during the day and holds outs His Hand during the day to receive the repentance of the one who has committed wrong during the night.” – [Muslim]

SOURCE : [QuotesDownload](http://quotesdownload.com/repentance-quotes/)

Comment: The link you refer to as a source does not cite any reference/source or chains of narration.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE! Please read the help sections on [How to reference material written by others](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). An answer that is a copy-and-paste in its entirety is considered plagiarism.